# Setting Background Image is not working

Tags: android

I am trying to set a background image for Relative Layout, but some error occured
here is My code thanks in advance

```
relative_topheader = new RelativeLayout(this);
relative_topheader.setId(1);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_topheader = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
Resources resources_topheader = getResources();
Drawable drawable_topheader = resources_topheader.getDrawable(R.drawable.headerbar_m);
relative_topheader.setBackground(drawable_topheader);
setContentView(1);
```

**My Log Cat:**

```
    05-21 11:40:05.655: I/dalvikvm(510): Could not find method android.widget.RelativeLayout.setBackground, referenced from method com.example.metromatineeapplicationlayer.MainActivity.onCreate
05-21 11:40:05.698: W/dalvikvm(510): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3324: Landroid/widget/RelativeLayout;.setBackground (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;)V
05-21 11:40:05.698: D/dalvikvm(510): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0052
05-21 11:40:05.788: D/AndroidRuntime(510): Shutting down VM
05-21 11:40:05.788: W/dalvikvm(510): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
05-21 11:40:05.795: E/AndroidRuntime(510): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 11:40:05.795: E/AndroidRuntime(510): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.RelativeLayout.setBackground
05-21 11:40:05.795: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at com.example.metromatineeapplicationlayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
05-21 11:40:05.795: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
05-21 11:40:05.795: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
05-21 11:40:05.795: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
05-21 11:40:05.795: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-21 11:40:05.795: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
05-21 11:40:05.795: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-21 11:40:05.795: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-21 11:40:05.795: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
05-21 11:40:05.795: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 11:40:05.795: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-21 11:40:05.795: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-21 11:40:05.795: E/AndroidRuntime(510):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.RelativeLayout.setBackground
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at com.example.metromatineeapplicationlayer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
05-21 11:42:44.945: E/AndroidRuntime(546):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post your error

Comment: use relative_topheader.setBackgroundDrawable (drawable_topheader);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error says there is no method found `setBackground` for `relativeLayout`

you have to use

```
relative_topheader.setBackgroundDrawable (drawable_topheader);
```

That will help

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```html
public void getpath() {
  File f = new File(new ImageLoader().fullPath + "/desiredFilename.png");
  if (f.exists()) {

   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
   Resources res = this.getResources();
   BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, bitmap);
   int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
   System.out.println(sdk);
   if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    System.out.println("less");
    bg.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);

   } else {
    System.out.println("great");
    bg.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);

   }
  } else {
   bg.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
     R.drawable.phils));
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
    relative_topheader.setBackground(drawable_topheader); //Added after API 16
} else {
    relative_topheader.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable_topheader); // Deprecated after API 16
}
```